# Combining filter and function_score - elastic search won't calculate score?

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I have `posts` index and i want to

a) Filter out all the posts by date i.e. return posts only created before the given `date`

b) Apply `function_score` to the results.

I came up with this query which looks kinda like this:

```
get posts/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "range": {
                "created_at": {
                  "lte": "2020-09-12T17:23:00Z"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "likes",
            "factor": 0.1,
            "modifier": "ln1p",
            "missing": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "sum"
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10
}
```

However the issue is that elastic search does NOT apply score to the results, all documents have `0.0` score. I can "trick" ES by moving filter into the functions, and then it does work, but i feel like it's not optimal, any idea why the query above won't return scores?

Example of a "cheat" query which DOES calculate scores for every document:

```
get posts/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "created_at": {
                "lte": "2020-09-12T17:22:58Z"
              }
            }
          },
          "weight": 100
        },
        {
          "gauss": {
            "created_at": {
              "origin": "2020-09-12T17:22:58Z",
              "scale": "1h",
              "decay": 0.95
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "likes",
            "factor": 0.1,
            "modifier": "ln1p",
            "missing": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter does not influence score. it's just 0 OR 1.
To be able to influence a score with a function_score query you have to use a function that calculate score (match, Match_phrase, geo query etc...)
You can have more details on context [in the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20Elasticsearch%20sorts%20matching,the%20more%20relevant%20the%20document.)

The field_value_factor [influence existing score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor) but in your first query you don't have any scoring at this stage, as it is nearly the same than ordering on like quantity.

In your second query you calculate a score which depends of the recentness of your docs, then influence it with likes. That's why it works.